# Prestashop autocomplete input type

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete, prestashop

I am developing a prestashop module , i have created some custom fields ate product page .
i have a field that get values by autocomplete  from a json

Here is the module tpl Field :

```
        <div class="form-group">

        <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Post 6:</label>

        <div class="col-lg-9">

            {*<input type="text" name="principi_name" value="{$principi_name}">*}

            {include

                file="controllers/products/textarea_lang.tpl"

                languages=$languages

                input_name='principi_name'

                class="textarea testingautocolplete"

                input_value=$principi_name}

        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the jquery :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    product_tabs['product_type'] = new function(){
         $('.testingautocolplete').autocomplete('http://www.domain.com/dbsearch.php', {
            width: 320,
            max: 4,
            highlight: false,
            multiple: true,
            multipleSeparator: " ",
            scroll: true,
            scrollHeight: 300,
        })

    }

});
```

The result on field is the all json :
I think I did a mistake but i cant find what:

[image]

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

We are not aware of the way you are using the autocomplete field but we have used it several times by using the following steps:

Add the following code to your JS code on the page (in document.ready javascript function)

```
$('YOUR_FIELD_ID').autocomplete(path_fold+"/FILE_PATH_TO_HANDLE_AJAX.php",{
     delay: 100,
     minChars: 1,
     autoFill: true,
     max: 20,
     matchContains: true,
     mustMatch: true,
     scroll: false,
     cacheLength: 0,
     multipleSeparator: '||',
     formatItem: function(item) {
         return item[0];
     },
     extraParams: {
         customerFilter: 1,
     }
 }).result(function(event, item) {
 //Code to use the result
 });
```

The php file that will be handling the ajax request will simply prepare and send data in the desired format.

Comment: Hello , Thank you for your response . I used your code and it is all right i case ate ajax.php i return simply a json like this : `[
"la-buona-cosmesi-che-fa-bene-allambiente-valori-e-valore-di-unimpresa-buona-dicono-di-noi",
"colore-naturale-per-viso-e-corpo-violetto-realizzato-con-alcanna"
]`  But it is not showing as dwropdown in the select form in case i return the result as the array as json encode `echo json_encode($simplearray)` img:http://prntscr.com/cqary9